# Extract values from dictionary to list in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have below dictionary in Python, and I would like to extract the value of "red" and apeend it to a list. I have the dictionary store in the variable "Reference" as per below:

```
Reference = {
    u'Message': u'', 
    u'Code': 0, 
    u'Data': [{u'Status': u'Running', u'InternalReferenceNumber': u'25333342818',  u'Currency': u'EUR', u'red': u'WA-1a9asd4sdfdas, u'PnlInfo': None},  
              {u'Status': u'Running', u'InternalReferenceNumber': u'25333342818',  u'Currency': u'EUR', u'red': u'WA-150824979asd4', u'PnlInfo': None}, 
              {u'Status': u'Running', u'InternalReferenceNumber': u'25333342818',  u'Currency': u'EUR', u'red': u'WA-1508249792364', u'PnlInfo': None}]
}
```

I have tried below code but somehow I do not achieve to get below output (i.e. a list with the value extracted from the dictionary for the key "red":

```
results = [WA-1a9asd4sdfdas,WA-150824979asd4,WA-1508249792364]
```

Code:

```
results = [ item['BetPlacementReference'] for item in Reference]
print results
```

Could you please advise how to get the desired list?

Thanks.

Comment: You're missing a quote in `u'WA-1a9asd4sdfdas`. Is that a typo?

Comment: @Reti43 Yes, it is a typo

Comment: Why `BetPlacementReference` and not `red`, in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do :

```
>>> out = []
>>> for ele in Reference['Data']: 
        out.append(ele['red']) 

>>> out
=> ['WA-1a9asd4sdfdas', 'WA-150824979asd4', 'WA-1508249792364']
```

Or, a single liner using `List comprehension` :

```
>>> [ ele['red'] for ele in Reference['Data'] ]
=> ['WA-1a9asd4sdfdas', 'WA-150824979asd4', 'WA-1508249792364']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
results = [item['red'] for item in Reference['Data']]
```

Honestly, I have no clue, why you try to find anthing with a key `'BetPlacementReference'` in your data :)

Answer (score 0):

What you could use to get the value of red for a certain point in data where 0 is the dictionary within the list:

```
Reference['Data'][0]['red']
```

This works because Data is subscriptable and so is each dictionary within the list.
To make it loop for every value we need to do:

```
red_list = []
for ref_dict in Reference['Data']:
    red_list.append(ref_dict['red'])
```

This will go through every part of `Data` in `Reference` adding the value of red to `red_list`.